# Cant seem to get pyopengl tutorial 4 to work

Tags: opengl

i am trying to work through some of the [tutorials for pyopengl](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/shader_4.html) and cant seem to get it working.

the only message i'm getting is a warning:

`python tutorial4.py`

`No handlers could be found for logger "OpenGL.arrays.numpymodule"`

no opengl context/screen pops up. script just exits.

id love any thoughts or feedback that might help me move forward,

https://gist.github.com/yvan/f34ad04c1ae32a41482ac1295871fffd

Answer (score 1):

solved:

i misspelled `glEnableVertexAttribArray` as `glEnableVerexAttribArray`. i'm not sure why opengl fails silently when i misspell the name of my pointer object. shouldn't it throw a name error or something? maybe `verex` is a thing?

ok well now we know.